# The jQuery `data` method don't convert value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in the view:

```
<div id="wiz_main"  data-place-schema="@Model.IsAgent">
...
</div>
```

This is the rendered code:

```
<div id="wiz_main" data-agent="True">
...
</div>
```

The code in the javascript file I write:

```
if ($('#wiz_main').data('agent'))
        limit = 1000;
else
        limit = 5;
```

The problem in that is, the `limit` always equals `5`. Why? I think `data` is smart and convert value to `bool`. I don't want to write the following:

```
if ($('#wiz_main').data('agent') == 'True')
       limit = 1000;
else
       limit = 5;
```

Version of `jQuery` is 1.7.2.

Comment: Try to change the data value to 'true'

Comment: @kidz: This is asp.net mvc rendered bool values. I can write js for it, but it's ugly.

Comment: Why don't you want to evaluate the string manually?

Comment: Something is amiss here. So long as `.data('agent')` doesn't return `null` or `false`, it should pass. That includes both `"True"` and `"true"`. Unless of course you change it to `if($('#wiz_main').data('agent') === true)`. Are you perhaps running this logic before `#wiz_main` is loaded in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if ( $('#wiz_main').attr('data-agent') == 'True' ){....}
```

**EDIT**

```
if ( $('#wiz_main').attr('data-agent') ){....}
```

Also, why don't you write `true` instead of `True` in your html?

Comment: `.attr` returns the value of the attribute as a string (or null, if not found), so calling `.val()` after `.attr()` is incorrect and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. But, I know this solution. I can't understand why `data` work not properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would set the data using the `data` method, it could be saved as a bool:

```
$('#wiz_main').data({ agent: true });
var agentbool = $('#wiz_main').data('agent');
console.log(typeof agentbool); //boolean
```

However, html5 data attributes will always be stored as a string

```
console.log(typeof $('#wiz_main').data('agent')); //string
```

The closest thing to a bool parse would be something like

```
function parseBool(str){
    return typeof str === 'string' && str.toLowerCase() === 'true';
}

var str = $('#wiz_main').data('agent');
var agentbool = parseBool(str);
```

Comment: `.data()` will attempt to convert values from strings to types. http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2